# ArcPro: Identifying features that are surrounded by a certain dimension of another polygon

Tags: python, gis, arcgis, esri

I am currently working on a project where I have two polygons files overlapping each over - Polygon A (blue) overlaps Polygon B (green). I would like to be able to identify the individual "blue" features in Polygon A that meet the certain criteria:

1. Are surrounded by a certain area of green on ALL sides (500ft radius)
2. Are surrounded by at least 500ft of green on any side

I have successfully used the "Pairwise buffer" tool to meet criteria #1...however since this tool generates a round buffer, it was not useful for criteria #2. Has anyone tried something similar, or have any suggestions on a route that may be successful?

Screen clipping from ArcPro map:

[image: Screen clipping from ArcPro map]

Answer (score 0):

To fulfill criterion #2, you can utilize the buffer already employed in criterion #1. Apply the "Select by Location" tool to the buffer layer, using the "Intersect" relation with the green polygon. This will select all buffers intersecting the green polygon. To identify the blue polygons meeting criterion #2, perform a spatial join between the blue polygons and buffers before running the selection.